# Stretch the tabs by screen width in Codename One

Tags: styles, codenameone, theming

I'm  using Blank theme for styling my app. In this theme tabs do not stretching by width. How can I fix them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the simplest way is to open one of the native themes from the Codename One SVN and look there (specifically at the theme constants) to see what was done to accomplish that.

In this case just define `tabsGridBool=true` (checked) in the theme constants.

Comment: This define broke my theme. Is there another way?

Comment: In what way did it break the theme?

Comment: Did you try pressing the theme section again? How did you style the tabs beyond that?

Comment: I managed to fix алл broken styles. But it was very unusual solution

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the problem so its possible you have an issue that might re-emerge later. I suggest deriving the native theme which is much simpler than starting from blank.

Comment: Starting with blank theme I strive to bring style to a single view of application on most platforms.

Comment: I would still recommend deriving native. It includes many hidden things that would make things MUCH simpler. E.g. spacing from the status bar on the top of the screen in iOS 7+.